# Jupyter notebook stopped running code and left cells unrun with [ ] instead of [*]

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, cell, interrupt

After running several cells for 6 to 7 hours, jupyter notebook just stopped. There should be [*] representing it's still running but it stopped running and show me several [ ]. I didn't do anything to stop it. I even didn't touch my computer when it was running. What's the problem? No error is shown.

Answer (score 0):

This Happens because Kernel stops or the display show that the process is till running, but if you have subsequent blocks of code to run then you can run and they would work sometimes.

It is a glitch that I faced too and as it is a big problem to take care of